# How do I use an open source GitHub repo in an unlocked package?

Tags: salesforcedx, unlocked-package, github

I have recently started exploring unlocked packages. I want to use features from https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns/fflib-apex-common in my packages.

I could clone the repo and convert it into an unlocked package but this will make it difficult to receive updates to the repo.

Is there an alternative to this approach?

Comment: What we did was to clone the repo and add it as Apex classes in our org.
Most of the updates to the classes are just license changes and updating the API version in the meta-xml files.  The base code doesn't change much over the year.s

Comment: Well in my opinion when you pull the update from git and bump up the version there you have an update to the unlocked package which can the be deployed in ur desired org. You can not count on code not changing.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll move ahead with cloning the classes and creating an unlocked package with them.